# What is the largest html file that can be loaded into a Android WebView?

Tags: java, android, html, webview, syntax-error

I have been trying to load a html file in a webview in a android activity and it seems that the html file is sending a exception ...

Unexpected End of output...

[Screen Shot of Maxed HTML File Retrieved from Android](http://imageshack.us/m/191/1433/cdce.png)
36.0 KB (36,864 bytes)  html file
I will check file and get back more code...

```
05-23 05:34:57.113: INFO/ActivityManager(60): Displayed gov.cdc.fluweekly/.WelcomeActivity: +2s511ms
05-23 05:34:58.135: ERROR/Web Console(347): SyntaxError: Parse error at file:///data/data/gov.cdc.fluweekly/files/flureport.html:28
05-23 05:36:04.018: INFO/InputReader(60): Device reconfigured: id=0x0, name=qwerty2, display size is now 480x800
05-23 05:36:04.018: WARN/InputReader(60):   Touch device did not report support for X or Y axis!
```

** Edit **
Just found a error in my html automation..  checking...

Extracted from html file....  could be causing parse error.

```
 'rgba(179,152,84,0.5)'],];var scatter1 =
```

Extra comma....   I am hoping it is my extra comma and not a filesize limitation...

Seems the html data is fully loading into the Webview though...  I have a embedded data object variable that I have a comma at the end of the array list of scatter plots.

Funny how a little Html parse exception can halt everything quick like...

here is the issue though.. not the comma..

```
osw.write("scatter1.Set('chart.title.yaxis', 'State Infection Level');\n");


        osw.write("if (!RGraph.isIE8()) {\n");
        osw.write("scatter1.Set('chart.zoom.factor', 2);\n");
        osw.write("scatter1.Set('chart.zoom.mode', 'area');\n");
        osw.write(" }\n");
        osw.write("scatter1.Draw();\n");                  
          Log.v("MainActivity", "refreshstats 12");
```

where I am writing html data on the fly to the android's file storage I did not append the \n  and many parse issues went bye bye...

***false alarm on the max file size on the html file...***

All good though....  I asked the question too early and didn't see the "SyntaxError" I was overly concerned with the file name size being so precise that I thought that perhaps it could of been a limitation of the system..  thank god it was just a Data block string builder error.

Comment: «Unexpected End of output» could also mean that the `</html>` tag is missing. Make sure your html file is actualy valid.

Comment: good call.  I will verify. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your issue may be other than what you're asking, the answer your question is

**Entirely dependant on the phone.**

In terms of browser capabilities, each version of Android has four variations (*two different JavaScript engines, two different "other" feature sets*) and on top of that since the worst Android phones are only slightly better than worn shoes and the others could crunch the numbers for launching a shuttle into orbit you should go with *as little markup as possible*.

If you really need to load a lot of stuff, make sure that especially the DOM of the loaded content is as simple possible since the complexity of DOM takes resources at almost an exponential rate.

Comment: Thanks you know it.  I was just poining fingers in the wrong direction...  eash.. 36k max file size...  like what was I thinking....